# Stripe Module stuck on "module:enable"

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, stripe

I am using Magento 2.3.1 and I am using the Mageside_Stripe module and I am following the instructions from their [site](https://mageside.com/media/attachment/file/s/t/stripe_installation.pdf), and I am tried to enable the module but it's just been stuck on that for over 15 minutes. What should my next steps be to fix it?

Edit:
When I checked my app/etc/config.php The module wasn't there and now my site is down.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using official stripe extension from here:

https://marketplace.magento.com/stripeofficial-stripe-payments.html

It's free.  Although without knowing more about your project I don't whether it's not got features that the Mageside version does. But *usually* official extensions have been tested more simply because they have more users and encounter and work through more bugs.

Comment: I bought the extension because I couldn't get the free one to work.

Comment: In that case all you can do is check through `var/log` to see if anything stands out.  Worst case scenario turn on php errors by editing `app/bootstrap.php`. It will be a debugging process.

Comment: Turns out it timed out and didn't enabled. So I reran the command and it is fine now!